# How do you counter a rotated camera?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

We are currently using opencv to track a planar rectangular target. While directly straight(no pitch), this works perfectly using findContours with solvePnp and returns a very accurate location of the target.

The problem is, is that obviously we get the different results once we increase the pitch. We know the pitch of the camera at all time.

How would I "cancel out" the pitch of the camera, and obtain coordinates as if the camera was facing straight ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case you can use an **affine transform** to map the quadrilateral seen by the camera back to the original rectangle. In your case the quadrilateral seen by the camera may be a good approximation of a parallelogram since only one angle is changing, but in real-world applications you can generally assume that the camera can have non-zero values for each of the three rotations (e.g. in pitch, yaw, and roll).

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

The transform allows you to calculate the matching coordinates (x,y) within the rectangle's plane given coordinates (x', y') in the image of the rectangle.